# Download file from other server return an empty file

Tags: php

I'm using this script to download an audio file from other server.

```
if(check_url($url)) {
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($url));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');

    readfile($url);
    die();
}
```

Where `$url` is the file URL.

On my Vagrant machine, the script works fine. But on server, the downloaded file has 0b.

Comment: Does the file exist? Check the path with [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: @JimWright Yes. I checked.

Comment: @ccKep So, how can I make to the file automatically downloaded?

Comment: What's the return value of `readfile` ? Is it `FALSE` ? (Note that this differs from `0`)